# Where is this Radvaz?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, shidduchim-dating

[Simcha LeIsh](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_47487_53.pdf) quotes the Radvaz siman 21 saying

> ואם באמת חש לסכנה הי
>    צריך לחוש למה שכתב בשערי רחמים (דף יא) שלנתק קשר תנאים הוא סכנה
>    גדולה, וטוב יותר לנתק קשר נישואין ע״י גט מלנתק קשר תנאים. ומהאי
>    טעמא בעת התנאים שוברים דוקא כלי חרס ותחת החופה שוברים כלי זכוכית,
>    משום דכלי חרס שנשבר אין לו תקנה לעשותו מחדש, וכך קשר תנאים אין
>    תקנה לנתק רק ע״י מיתה וגלגול, משא״כ כלי זכוכית שנשבר דהיינו נישואין
>    יש לו תקנה ע״י גט לעשותו מחדש.

I looked in Shu"t Radvaz ([21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1952&pgnum=16)) and it has nothing to do with Shidduchim at all. Where's this Radvaz?

Comment: For context, the Rabaz ([here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1235&st=&pgnum=412)) was referring to a case where a person was considering breaking the engagement because he was afraid of danger resulting from marrying a woman with the same name as his mother. By way of discouraging the person from breaking a preexisting engagement for this reason, the Rabaz suggests that it is more dangerous to break an engagement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a responsum of [Rabaz](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%96%D7%90%D7%91_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%9F) (vol. 2: Even Haezer, ch. 21) (of 19th-20th century Romania); not [Radvaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra) (of 15th-16th century Egypt).